# Finding the orthogonal complement of a subset of a Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Take the Hilbert space $\ell^2$ of all $x=(x_1,x_2,...x_i...)$ such that $x_i \in \mathbb R$ for all $n$, with $\sum_{i=1}^∞ x_i^2<∞$ and the defined inner product $<x,y> = \sum_{i=1}^∞x_iy_i$.

Take a subset of this space $S$. Let such $S$ be the set of all elements $x=(x_1,x_2,...x_i...)$ with the condition that $x_{2n} = 0$ for $n\ge1$. Then what is the orthogonal complement of $S$?

So far, clearly all such $x_{2n}$ are in the orthogonal complement, since the inner product of these elements with any element of $S$ is zero. $0$ too is of course in $S^⊥$. Where do I go from here? It's fine to say what $S^⊥$ 'is', but how do I actually completely define it?

Comment: "all such $x_{2n}$ are in the orthogonal compliment (sic)"  what do you mean by $x_{2n}$ here?

Comment: Your $S$ is the set of all things in $\ell^2$ that look like
$$(x_1,0,x_3,0,x_5,0,\ldots).$$
I reckon that anything in $\ell^2$ that looks like
$$(0,x_2,0,x_4,0,x_6,\ldots)$$
is in $S^\perp$. What do you think?

Comment: @AnginaSeng I don't know how to phrase this, so hopefully it'll make sense. How do we know what elements are actually in $S$? E.g, what's to say the first 2 or 10 or 100 elements will or won't satisfy the property?

Answer (score 1):

You have a Hilbert base for $S$ namely $X=\{e_{2n-1}|n\geqslant 1\}$ (that is, $S$ is the closure of the linear subspace spanned by $X$), where $e_{k}=(e_{k,i})_{i}$ is the vector having $e_{k,i}=0$ for $i\neq k$ and $e_{k,k}=1$. If $X$ is a dense subset of $S$, then $$S^\perp=X^\perp=\{z|\langle z,x\rangle=0\forall x\in X\}$$
(clearly $S^\perp\subseteq X^\perp$, while $X^\perp\subseteq S^\perp$ because every $s\in S$ is the limit of a sequence $x_n$ in $X$ and so $z\in X^\perp\rightarrow\langle z,s\rangle=\langle z,\lim_nx_n\rangle=\lim_n\langle z,x_n\rangle=0\rightarrow z\in S^\perp$).

In this case the dense subset is $\{e_{2n-1}|n\geqslant1\}$, so $$S^\perp=\{z|\langle z,e_{2n-1}\rangle=0\forall n\geqslant 1\}=\{z|z_{2n-1}=0\forall n\geqslant 1\}$$